# Multiply based on condition then sum results ( multiply if empty <> ) in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need help in writing a formula in cell b7. The formula must look to the right and multiply the nonempty cells by the corresponding value in row 3, and I would like to sum up the results.

File link provided.

[FILE LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/137QMOA7X96cytAzJw4oYWek9EaOB_kxg1Jbzsu3eHLg/template/preview)

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5kOB.png)

Comment: Have you decided which you are using?

Comment: In addition to indicating whether you are using Excel ***or*** Google Sheets (they are not the same), the math and explanation shown in our post and ScreenShot to do not match. You say that you are looking to multiply values across rows (e.g., Row 7) by values in Row 3; but then you multiplies "John's" 0.269 by the value in Row 4. The next value in Row 7 was multiplied by the value in Row 3 (but rounded up instead of down). And the final value from Row 7 multiplied by Row 3??? is incorrect (you show 20,004 in one place and 20,114 in another). Please carefully edit your post and examples.

Comment: Thanks, solar, I updated the post with the corrections. I Am working with google sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my comment to your original post.

That said, I will try to explain how to approach this as I think you *intend*. (This solution will be a ***Google Sheets solution*** which will not work in Excel.)

The first thing you will need to do is to delete ***everything*** from Row 11 down: all of your examples and notes must be deleted for the following proposed formula to work correctly.

Once you have no superfluous data below your main chart, delete ***everything*** from B6:B (including the header "Total").

Then, place the following formula in cell B6:

`={"TOTAL"; FILTER(MMULT(C7:G*1, TRANSPOSE(C$3:G$3*1)), A7:A<>"")}`

This formula will return the header text "TOTAL" (which you can change within the formula itself if you like) followed by the calculation you want for each row where a name is listed in A7:A.

`MMULT` is a difficult function to explain, but it multiplies one matrix ("grid") or numbers by another matrix ("grid") and returns the sum of all products per row (or per column, depending on how you set it up) —— which is what you are trying to do.

`MMULT` must have every element of both matrices be a real number. To convert potential nulls to zeroes, you'll see `*1` appended to each range (since null times 1 is zero).

This assumes that all data entered into C7:G and C3:G3 will *always* be either a number or null. If you enter text, you'll throw the formula into an error. If you think accidental text entries in those ranges are possible, use this version instead:

`={"TOTAL"; FILTER(MMULT(IFERROR(C7:G*1, ROW(C7:G)*0), TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(C$3:G$3*1, COLUMN(C$3:G$3)*0))), A7:A<>"")}`

The extra bits use `IFERROR` to exchange error-producing entries with zeroes, since `MMULT` must have every space in both matrices filled with a real number.

Comment: Thanks, Erik Tyler those solutions are genius. great work you know your stuff. Amazing!!.

Comment: Glad it fit your need, Giovanni. If you would, please take a moment to mark the answer post "Best Answer." This lets the extended contributor community know that that issue has already been solved; and it makes it easier for future site visitors like yourself to more quickly find relevant solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again, Erik, for your time helping me out. Your quick response and great explanation are much appreciated. I looked at your fantastic website, https://thebestadvicesofar.com/choose-book/. I will be purchasing one of your books. Keep up the great work, Erik.

Comment: I hope that the book you choose will come to you at just the right time for where life has you right now, Giovanni, and will offer you some practical new "life tool" for happier living and more connection with others.